# Weird Facebook ids

Tags: ios, facebook

I have two Facebook Application, both of them is under development.
One of it was created very long ago, while the other one was pretty new.

Ever since i upgraded to the new iOS Facebook SDK 3.14.1.
Im having a lot of weird issues. One main issue would be the Facebook identifier.
For some unknown reasons, i'm getting a very weird id when i'm logged in with the same Facebook user in my two different application.

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting app-scoped User IDs now, because you're apparently using v2.0 of the Graph API.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: any ideas how to get the real Facebook id?

Comment: Erase the old User IDs and use the app-scoped ones. As your app is not in production this shouldn't be a big problem I guess. There's no official way to get the global User IDs with Graph API v2.0. You can use the Business Mapping API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business) if you need to match the Users of App1 with those of App2.